# change state of toggle button by clicking another toggle button with setSelected event

Tags: java, button, calculator

I want to change state of my toggle button by clicking another toggle button. my code doesnt work like that. there is a problem with that part:

```
private void jToggleButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        processValue("+");
        if(values.contains("+"))
            jToggleButton12.setSelected(true);
        else
            jToggleButton12.isSelected();
    }

private void jToggleButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    processValue("-");
    if(values.contains("-"))
        jToggleButton13.setSelected(true);
    else
        jToggleButton13.isSelected();
}                                               

private void jToggleButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    processValue("*");
    if(values.contains("*"))
        jToggleButton14.setSelected(true);
    else
        jToggleButton14.isSelected();
}                                               

private void jToggleButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    processValue("/");
    if(values.contains("/"))
        jToggleButton15.setSelected(true);
    else
        jToggleButton15.isSelected();
}
```

This code only selects the joggle button and when I click it is still selected.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually handling every toggle and un-toggle of every button, you can just add those buttons to a `ButtonGroup`

Code would be something like so:

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

group.add(jToggleButton1);
group.add(jToggleButton2);
group.add(jToggleButton3);
//...etc
```

This will automatically handle un-toggling of every button. Now you only need to handle what every button will do.

Comment: I need a code like jToggleButton.setSelected(?); but I couldnt give a parameter for  "?" part. On if-else statement: if part works but else part doesnt work the way I want

Comment: `isSelected();` returns a boolean telling you whether the button is selected or not. To set the selection state of a button use a boolean as the parameter of `setSelected();` But the `ButtonGroup` will automatically handle the selecting and de-selecting (toggling). All you will need to handle is the `processValue("/");` method of each button. Using an array as shown in @Juvanis's answer will work well for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to achieve the behaviour of radio buttons, i.e. only one is selected at a time. To implement this, I suggest you to use an array of your JToggleButton instances. When action performed, iterate over this array and unselect all buttons, after that set the specific button according to your specific condition.

```
JToggleButton[] buttons = new JToggleButton[5];
...
private void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                                
        processValue("+");

        for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("+"))
            jToggleButton12.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: By using this code how can I create class "JToggleButton" in my package?

Comment: @cansukartal you don't need to create that class, it is a part of standard Java library in the package 'javax.swing.JToggleButton', just import it.

Comment: Its imported but now I have a problem with my generated code If I can copy here my whole code maybe you can understand problems easier how can I show you my whole code?